# MySQL: Select with first and last day of previous month

Tags: mysql, date

Using PhpMyadmin, I have this sentence working:

```
SELECT id_order as Ref FROM t_orders WHERE DATE(invoice_date) = CURDATE()
```

Now I want to reemplace "current date" (CURDATE) for the first day of previous month in advance.

---

The answer of Ankit Bajpai solved my problem (thank you):

```
SELECT id_order as Ref FROM t_orders WHERE DATE(invoice_date) >= concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-'),'01');
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Your code should work... is it not giving you the expected results? If not can you post some test data and expected results?

Comment: See the tags and what the OP linked to @Strawberry

Comment: Ok - maybe I've got it back to front

Comment: Im executing the code using PhpMyAdmin. Result is a white page

Comment: You are using PhpMyAdmin. This means you need a query which should work on Mysql rather than MSSQL. Please correct your tag. All the answers are for MSSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in MYSQL you can try the below

**First day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month)
```

**First day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT id_order as Ref
FROM t_orders 
WHERE DATE(invoice_date) >= concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-'),'01');
```

Comment: This gives the same results as what the OP posted, `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)` but with less functions. Am i missing something?

Comment: I received the error #1064 "something is wrong in your syntax"

Comment: THANK YOU very much. It is working, you can't imagine the happiness I'm feeling.. :-). 
BTW, I voted your answer, but system said till my reputation is higher, it's not valuable.

Comment: Hehehehehehe. Your happiness is more valuable to me than your vote. Cheers......!!

Answer (score -1):

For MS SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @firstDayOfLastMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
DECLARE @lastDayOfLastMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

SELECT @firstDayOfLastMonth;
SELECT @lastDayOfLastMonth;
```

Answer (score -1):

After reading closely... you want the entire month, of the previous month. You can do this:

```
SELECT id_order as Ref FROM t_orders 
WHERE 
DATE(invoice_date) >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
AND
DATE(invoice_date) <= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

OR

```
SELECT id_order as Ref FROM t_orders 
WHERE 
MONTH(DATE(invoice_date)) = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Remember I want to use with PhpMyadmin.
Your first code returns:
1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'dateiff

And the second one "1305 function DATEADD does not exist"

Comment: You tagged SQL server and linked to a SQL server post. Everyone that replied did so with that in mind so you should have constructed your question better.