# How to filter only finished months on SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to filter my query with only closed months, so today (17/11/2022) would return only 31/10/2022 and before. I have tried the following:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dc.data) <= (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE()) - 1)
```

So I get the current date, extract the month and subtract 1, then filter <= that month right? Also, dc.data is on the right date format, and it's working properly

But here is the problem, it's filtering past Years with months 1-10 too, that filter should be applied only to current year, and **still show past years with all months**, how could I do this?

This query is being written on Apache Superset SQL editor, so I have some limitations on functions I think... the database is MySQL (edited)

PS: I was also wondering if there is a way to optimize this query, not sure if this is a good way of handling dates

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154803/mysql-select-with-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month Something like `WHERE db.data < select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day`

Comment: You can run `select version();` to find out which database you are really using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name returns 5.7.12. With this info I'm sure it's MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You need also to comapre the years, if you want the actual year

```
WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dc.data) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE()) 
      AMD EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dc.data) <= (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURDATE()) - 1)) OR EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dc.data) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE())
```

or use the last day of the previous moth to get the l

```
WHERE dc.data <= (date_trunc('MONTH', now()) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
```

you should have an INDEX on data to get the data faster

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I still need to bring up the past years, unfiltered, not only the current year

Comment: i added another solutiona and adepted my last onel, now both will work.

Comment: Your solution helped me get to: WHERE dc.data < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')

Answer (score 1):

Postgres provides a convent function date_trunc (see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)). One the options is truncating to the `month`, which will return the first day of the parameter. So

```
where dc.data < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

Comment: Just found out its MySQL, the equivalent for PostgreSQL date_trunc would be EXTRACT and work with that?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the answer! Worked with the MySQL equivalent of date_trunc which is: DATE_FORMAT(SYSDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')

Answer (score 1):

MySQL equivalent to TRUNC/DATE_TRUNC is

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

So my final result was

```
WHERE dc.data < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```